# Android studio error “E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error: GL_INVALID_VALUE”

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, android-glide

I've got this error before crashing my app

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_VALUE
A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/BakedOpRenderer.cpp:67
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 29871 (RenderThread)
```

Maybe because I load too many images at the same time while using a loop cycle

```
GlideApp.with(appContext).clear(imagePreview)
            GlideApp.with(imagePreview.context)
                    .load(post.preview)
                    .placeholder(placeholder)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .into(imagePreview)
```

If I split the items to loop, it works, but I'd like to find a way to suspend the cycle and free up space before resuming it. Are there any libraries to do that?